# Renaming Sheets just made within loops while finding and replacing cell value

Tags: excel, vba

My code currently creates 9 sheets. It's to equal the number of cells in row 1 starting at column C in the 'LLP Disc Sheet', which is 9. This number changes whenever the user deletes cells in that row or add more cells.

I now want to rename each sheet produced (the 9 sheets) to equal a cell value in the first row of the 'LLP Disc Sheet'. For instance, one sheet will be named 77777 (C1 in 'LLP Disc Sheet') the other sheet is 66666 (D1 in 'LLP Disc Sheet') , 55555 (E1 in 'LLP Disc Sheet') , and so on. I keep getting an error whenever I tried to do ActiveSheet.rename

Lastly, I want to change B1's formula in each sheet of the 9 sheets produced to match the name of the sheet. The 9 sheets produced are copies of the "MasterCalculator" So I tried to do find/replace and still had an error.

```
Set rng = ws.Range("B1") 'initialize the target range variable
rng.Replace "=+'LLP Disc Sheet'!C", "=+'LLP Disc Sheet'!D"  'but I want to somehow loop it so it continues to K, because that's how many sheets there ar
```

Module 1

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewSheets()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("MasterCalculator")
Set sh = Sheets("LLP Disc Sheet")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
For i = 2 To Range("A1:Z1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Sheets("MasterCalculator").Copy After:=sh
Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for the first bit?

You should add some error trapping in case there are no constants (and might need a check for valid sheet names).

For the formula bit, sounds like you can replace the original sheet name with `sh.name`?

```
Sub NewSheets()

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("MasterCalculator")
Set sh = Sheets("LLP Disc Sheet")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

With ws.Range("A1:Z1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
   For i = 2 To .Count
       ws.Copy After:=sh
       sh.Name = .Cells(i).Value
   Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't work. A run-time error '1004 occurred. It says sh.Name is an invalid name for a sheet or chart.

Comment: Well as I said there are restrictions on sheet names.